Showing explicitly that every 2-form on a plane minus the origin is exact
Consider $X=\Bbb R^2-0$. Since it deformation retracts onto the unit circle $S^1$, the second de Rham cohomology of the manifold $X$ is zero. This means that every 2-form $hdxdy$ on $X$ is exact. But can we find an explicit 1-form $fdx+gdy$ on $X$ satisfying $d(fdx+gdy)=hdxdy$, i.e. $g_x-f_y=h$? I cannot see how to define $f$ and $g$ from $h$.

Have you tried using the Poincare lemma for star-shaped domains?

@MikhailKatz But how can we use the Poincare lemma for star-shaped domains to the not-star-shaped space $X$?

If you remove a ray, it becomes star-shaped.  Then the Poincare lemma can be applied.  It remains to check that one gets the same answer approaching the ray from two different sides.

Think of $\Bbb R^2-\{0\}$ in polar coordinates (i.e., as a cylinder). You're given the $2$-form $\omega=f(r,\theta)\,dr\wedge d\theta$ with $r>0$ and $f(r,0)=f(r,2\pi)$. Let $F(r,\theta) = \int_1^r f(u,\theta)\,du$ and set $\eta=F(r,\theta)\,d\theta$. Then $\eta$ is well-defined (and smooth), and clearly $d\eta=\omega$.
